# Android delete list item from cursor adapter

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, listitem

I already implemented CursorAdapter to show phone contact list, it works fine. Now I want to implement delete item on click.. But item will delete from only list, not from phone data base.. and delete function will implement in CursorAdapter. Tried but unable to do this.. Help me..

My code is here..

```
ImageButton remFrnd = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.remove_frnd);
remFrnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.request_animate);

        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
                //final int position = listContacts.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent());
                // datalist.remove(position);
                deleteRecordWithId(itemId);
                cursor.requery();
                // myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        view.startAnimation(fadeOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `deleteRecordWithId(itemId);` ?

Comment: i am trying this..but this is for database..so they are not necessary..

Comment: den post your database class too.fisrt get your list selected item,den get it from database and delete whole row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the entry from the list ONLY (not from the phone book) make sure your adapter does not load the data from the phone book every time you fire DataSetChanged - like a cursor adapter would probably do...
Instead load the data from the phone book put it into some datastructure and then an ArrayAdapter or something like this...

***EDIT:***

```
private ListView initializeListView() {
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<Person> persons = loadPersonsFromMyChosenStorage();
    if(persons==null){
        //we haven't stored persons yet
        persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        String whereName = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String firstname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
            String lastname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            if(firstname!=null&&lastname!=null){
                persons.add(new SimplePerson(firstname,lastname));
            }
        }
        storePersonsToMyChosenStorage(persons);
    }
    if(lv!=null) {
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, persons));
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
    return lv;
}
```

Comment: exactly.i want this...but there is a small problem that when i reopen the application then it shows all,i want to delete this forever from the list..plz help me..

Comment: Load your data once and persist it (many options: [storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) ) After that you load your data from there...